# Difference between design-time and runtime framework

Tags: frameworks, runtime, design-time

What is the difference between a design-time and a runtime framework, as in "Oracle ADF is a Java EE design-time and runtime framework"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The distinction is between `design time` and `run time`, not frameworks. The fraweworks are for both of these functions.

Design time means during code and UI design, when one is writing code and using graphic designers to design a UI.

Run time is when the application is actually running.

The framework assists in both of these distinct phases.

Comment: Thank you. So most frameworks I've seen are design-time. I guess my question really is why people needs runtime framework.

Comment: @Martin08 - A framework is for both design and run time. There is no such thing as a "runtime framework" that doesn't have design time elements.

Comment: Using JAXB as an example, there is a design time piece for generating classes from an XML schema, and a runtime framework where the design time artifacts are used to generate objects from XML.

Comment: I just found the explanation for the case of Oracle ADF framework in JSR-227. In this context, the design-time framework requires prior domain knowledge to work with its classes/methods. In contrast, the runtime framework offers a developer methods to find out things about the domain and works on them at runtime. It's something of the same nature to Blaise's answer or the reflection framework in Java.